# Solutions to non-linear second order differential equations of the form $y''(t) = \frac{1}{y(t)^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been trying to find the solutions to the following differential equation that I found in a math book. I am really lost, so anything will do (hints and solutions alike)

$$y''(t)-\frac{1}{y(t)^{2}}=0.$$

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: *Hint*: think of $\quad y''(t)\quad$ as $\quad y'(t) \dfrac{\mathrm{d}y'}{\mathrm{d}y}.$ This way you can write:
$$ y'(t) \dfrac{\mathrm{d}y'}{\mathrm{d}y} = \dfrac{1}{y^2(t)},$$
or:
$$ y'(t) \mathrm{d}y' = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2(t)}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$y'' = \frac{1}{y^2}
$,
try
$y = at^b$.

$y' = ab t^{b-1}$
and
$y'' = ab(b-1)t^{b-2}$,
so we want
$ab(b-1)t^{b-2}
=\frac1{a^2t^{2b}}
=\frac1{a^2}t^{-2b}
$
so that
$ab(b-1) = \frac1{a^2}$
and
$b-2 = -2b$.

From this last,
$3b = 2$
or
$b = \frac23$.

From the first,
$a^3 
= \frac1{b(b-1)}
= \frac1{-\frac23 \frac13}
=-\frac{9}{2}
$.

A solution is therefore
$y(t) 
=-\sqrt[3]{9/2}t^{2/3}
$.

As a check,
$y'(t) 
=-\frac23\sqrt[3]{9/2}t^{-1/3}
$,
$y''(t) 
=\frac{2}{9}\sqrt[3]{9/2}t^{-4/3}
=(\frac{2}{9})^{2/3}t^{-4/3}
$,
$y^2(t) 
=(9/2)^{2/3}t^{4/3}
$,
$\frac1{y^2(t)} 
=\frac1{(9/2)^{2/3}t^{4/3}}
=\frac1{(9/2)^{2/3}}t^{-4/3}
=(2/9)^{2/3}t^{-4/3}
$.

---

Another way,
which I will leave incomplete,
is to start with

$y'y'' = \frac{y'}{y^2}
$,
or
$\frac12(y'^2)' = -\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)'
$
or
$\frac12y'^2 = -\frac{1}{y}+c
$
or
$\frac12y' = \sqrt{c-\frac{1}{y}}
$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply with $y'$, integrate
$$
\frac12 y'^2+\frac1y=E
$$
Now it remains to integrate
$$
\int dt = \int\sqrt{\frac12\frac{y}{Ey-1}}\,dy
$$

Comment: Wolfram can do it. Inverting it to get y in terms of t looks impossible.